# BlockBuilderApi<Block> Trait bounds within node/src/service and rpc

Tags: babe, nodes

I am having a problem satisfying all of the trait bounds within the `node` crate. I am using the `polkadot-v0.9.17` branch of substrate, as was recommended on another question here.

It is calling `sc_consensus_babe::import_queue`, which I'm pretty sure is here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.17/client/consensus/babe/src/lib.rs#L1709

The function has this bound on the where clause:

```
    Client::Api: BlockBuilderApi<Block> + BabeApi<Block> + ApiExt<Block>,
```

This function is called from `node/src/service.rs`, and looks exactly like this: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.17/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs#L205

Everything in my `service.rs` matches the substrate copy. How can I ensure the expected traits are satisfied when calling `import_queue`?

```
 Compiling node-template v4.0.0-dev (substrate-simple-template/node)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RuntimeApiImpl<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, node_runtime::RuntimeApi>>: sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>` is not satisfied
    --> node/src/service.rs:126:21
     |
126  |     let import_queue = sc_consensus_babe::import_queue(
     |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>` is not implemented for `RuntimeApiImpl<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>, node_runtime::Call, MultiSignature, (frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<node_runtime::Runtime>, frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<node_runtime::Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<node_runtime::Runtime>)>>, node_runtime::RuntimeApi>>`
     |
note: required by a bound in `import_queue`
    --> /home/max/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/client/consensus/babe/src/lib.rs:1736:15
     |
1736 |     Client::Api: BlockBuilderApi<Block> + BabeApi<Block> + ApiExt<Block>,
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `import_queue`
```

Comment: You should not need to call `import_queue` manually AFAI but instead be able to get an import queue by calling [new_partial](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.17/bin/node/cli/src/command.rs#L109).

Comment: It is within the ‘new_partial’ function where the error is occurring.

Comment: Sorry but could you provide the sour-code? There are a lot of things that can go wrong here.

Comment: a hunch: might be your lock file has multiple substrate versions upstream. Look there to confirm you are really using uniform upstream commit for all of substrate

Comment: i usually do `cargo tree` to check multiple versions of substrate injected and which package is culprit. most likely you will need to adjust your dependencies and possibly even patch some in root Cargo.lock

Comment: Closing this post because no additional details were included to help diagnose the particular issue.